# How can I remove a single Exchange 2010 CAS server from allowing Outlook to connect internally?

Tags: exchange-2010

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue with our Exchange 2010 setup and need to remove one of our CAS servers from allowing Outlook users to connect it internally. However, I'd still like for it to be functional with regards to OWA, ActiveSync, etc.

I'm fairly certain this needs to be done within EMC at Server Configuration > Client Access > Server Name, but I'm not quite sure what setting I need to change.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that in the EMC, but I believe it can be done with `Set-RpcClientAccess` (if you want to lockout specific clients) in the EMS or Remove-RpcClientAccess to disable it altogether. **Make sure you know how to reconfigure it before doing it though.**

[Microsoft Reference for Set-RpcClientAccess](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351072%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx)

Comment: The problem I see with this is that I don't want to block clients, I just want to temporarily disable a single CAS server from serving as a server to Outlook clients (note: I don't mean OWA or anything else).

Comment: Exactly you can scope Set-RpcClientAccess to a specific Server to block specific clients. So you block all outlook 2007,2010,2013 clients from connecting only to that server. OWA and ActiveSync will still be working on that box.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now. I'll take a look at doing that then, thank you.